# Show the cirucumcircles of all triangles $PAB$ have the same radius

Tags: geometry, circles

Given $2$ circles $W_1$ and $W_2$ which intersect at points $X$,$Y$. Let $P$ be an arbitrary point on $W_1$. Suppose the lines $PX$,$PY$ meet $W_2$ again at points $A$,$B$ respectively. Prove that the circumcircles of all triangles $PAB$ have the same radius.

**MY TRY:-**
I tried to use coordinate geometry, but it didn't work. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "the circumcircles of all triangles $PAB$ have he same radius"? It doesn't make sense, because this sentence only mentions a single triangle.

Comment: @EvanAad Probably, the OP wants us to prove that for all such points $P$, the circumradii will be equal.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be the centers of circles $W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively. Denote by $$\alpha_1 = \angle \, XPY = \angle \, APB = \angle \, XPB = \frac{1}{2} \, \text{arc}_{W_1}(XY)$$ and
 $$\alpha_2 = \angle \, XBY = \angle \, XAY =  \angle \, XBP = \frac{1}{2} \, \text{arc}_{W_2}(XY)$$
Notice that these two arcs, and therefore the angles $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$,  are independent of the choice of the point $P$ and the consequent location of the chord $AB$.

Then  $$\text{arc}_{W_2}(AB) =2 \,  \angle \, AXB = 2 \, (\angle \, XPB + \angle \, XBP ) = 2\,(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$$
Hence, the arc $\text{arc}_{W_2}(AB)$ on circle $W_2$ which does not contain points $X, Y$ is of constant length $2\,(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$ for any choice of the point $P$ on $W_1$. Therefore the chord $AB$ is also of constant length for any choice of the point $P$ on $W_1$. The circle circumscribed around any configuration $PAB$ has radius $$R = \frac{AB}{2 \, \sin(\angle \, APB)} = \frac{AB}{2 \, \sin(\alpha_1)}$$ so it is independent on the choice of the point $P$ on $W_1$.